# I have collectionView inside of Tableview cell. It return always Zero. How can I solve it?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, mobile-development

I have collectionView inside of Tableview cell. When I take data from firebase, I save the data to array and then try to put it on collection view. However, even if I put data in array manually, my array.count show always zero and There is no thing in my collection view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentuserArray.append(User(email: "x@gmail.com", image: "ASD"))
    currentuserArray.append(User(email: "y@gmail.com", image: "ASD"))
    print(currentuserArray.count)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    getDataFromFirebaseToTakeUsers()

}
```

in there, the value of currentuserArray.count is 2.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(currentuserArray.count)
        return currentuserArray.count // this looks like 0, however at the top, it was 2.
    }
```

However; in there, the value of userMailArray.count is 0. So, I don't have anything on my collectionView. How can it be possible ?

Comment: Is it collection or table ?

Comment: you are not following life cycle of view controller. in order to populate your array you have to call "collectionview.reloadData" in your getDataFromFirebaseToTakeUsers() after fetching data to array. if you didn't do that your array will always be empty. because collectionview methods call out before your viewdidload method.... hopes you understand... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `getDataFromFirebaseToTakeUsers`is asynchronous you need to

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

inside the completion

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewCell") as! ReviewTableViewCell
        cell.clCollectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }

Comment: I already reload my collection view inside of cellForRowAt function of tableviewCell. Is it not enough

Comment: no you shouldn't reload it inside `cellForRowAt` do it inside `getDataFromFirebaseToTakeUsersis `